# Codeigniter 3.1.11 - Login session variable not encrypted php 7.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt the session variable but it couldn't work. I am using php7.2 and Codeigniter 3.1.11. I have another project with Codeigniter 3.1.6 that working fine but I don't know what actual issue has occurred on my project.

Here I have my code in common_library.php

```
<?php

Class Common_library {

    private $CI;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
    }

    function is_session_loggedin($user_type) {
        $uring = $this->CI->encryption->decrypt($this->CI->session->userdata('uring'));
        $sql = $this->CI->db->get_where('users', array('user_id' => $uring, 'status' => 'Active', 'user_type' => $user_type));
        if ($sql->num_rows() != 1) {
            redirect(site_url(''));
        }
    }
```

and I have set the session variable in login_library.php check the below code

```
public function setUserLoginSession($user_id) {
        $users = $this->CI->login_model->getUserInformation($user_id);
        if (isset($users) && count($users) == 1) {

            $session_data = array(
                'user_id' => $users[0]['user_id'],
                'name' => $users[0]['name'],
                'profile_image' => $users[0]['profile_image'],
                'email' => $users[0]['email'],
                'user_type' => $users[0]['user_type'],
                'uring' => $this->CI->encryption->encrypt($users[0]['user_id'])
            );
            $this->CI->session->set_userdata($session_data);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Also please find the code in autoload.php and config.php files

//autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session', 'encryption','common_library');
```

//config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```